# How to correctly unzip .7z archive with SevenZFile class?

Tags: java, android, 7zip

I want to unzip a .7z archive but I'm facing a weird issue.
Maybe I didn't understood well how to use the "SevenZFile" class from org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.20.

Here is my method which use the SevenZfile class :

```
    public static void extract7z(File input, File outputDir) throws IOException {
    SevenZFile sevenZFile = new SevenZFile(input);
    SevenZArchiveEntry entry;
    while ((entry = sevenZFile.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
            File outputFile = new File(outputDir, entry.getName());
            outputFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            IOUtils.copy(sevenZFile.getInputStream(entry), outputStream);
            outputStream.close();
        }
    }
    sevenZFile.close();
}
```

I called this method in the same file in this method :

```
    public void saveImage(Context myContext, String myDataset) throws IOException {

    AssetManager assetManager = Objects.requireNonNull(myContext).getAssets();
    String[] archives = null;
    String archiveName = myDataset + ".7z";
    String archivePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + archiveName;
    File archive = new File(archivePath);
    File picturesFolder = new File(myContext.getExternalFilesDir(null).getParent(), "Pictures");
    picturesFolder.mkdirs();
    try {
        archives = assetManager.list("photos/"+myDataset+"/"+"archive");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("tag", "Failed to get asset file list.", e);
    }
    if (archives != null) {
            InputStream in;
            OutputStream out;
            try {
                in = assetManager.open("photos/" + myDataset + "/" +"archive"+ "/" +"dataset3.7z");
                File outFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + archiveName);
                out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
                copyFile(in, out);
                in.close();
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                extract7z(archive, picturesFolder);
                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(myContext, new String[]{outFile.toString()}, null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        Log.i("External Storage", "Scanned" + path + ":");
                        Log.i("External Storage", "uri " + uri);

                    }
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("tag", "Failed to copy asset file: " + archiveName, e);

        }
    } else {
        Log.e("Error NPE", "null");
    }
}
```

In this method I copy and then paste my file dataset3.7z from asset file to the external public directory. This step is working fine.
But, then, when I wanted to unzip this file in the phone I faced this error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1000; index=-1
```

from this line :

```
IOUtils.copy(sevenZFile.getInputStream(entry), outputStream);
```

I don't understand this error, I know my archive is 1000 images, but do I have to loop through the files to unzip them one by one?
Does this class work like that ?